# How to get the claims from a JWT token in JSON into the object?

Tags: json, jwt, jq

I have a JSON object that contains a JWT token. I would like to extract the claims from the token and put them into the JSON object, replacing the token. Here is my object:

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "time": "now",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiYm9iYnkiLCJjb2xvciI6ImJsdWUiLCJ0cmVlIjoiZWxtIn0K.9JCVXpkI6ICc5RnIsIiN1IzUIJiOicGbhJye"
}
```

The JWT contains these claims (base64 encoded in the middle field of the JWT, delimited by dots):

```
{
    "name": "bobby",
    "color": "blue",
    "tree": "elm"
}
```

How can I pull out the claims and put them into the JSON in place of the JWT token using jq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [string division](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#multiplication-division-modulo) to split the token on dots, the `@base64d` filter to base64 decode the data, and the `fromjson` filter to turn the string into JSON.

The `|=` update operator can be used to assign the result back to the `.token` field.

```
jq '.token |= ((. / ".")[1] | @base64d | fromjson)' file.json
```

Result:

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "time": "now",
  "token": {
    "name": "bobby",
    "color": "blue",
    "tree": "elm"
  }
}
```

You can also use the `splits` function to split the token on dots:

```
jq '.token |= ([splits("\\.")][1] | @base64d | fromjson)' file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the value of `.token` at the dot into an array, take the second item, and use `@base64d` to decode base64, and `fromjson` to interpret the output as JSON:

```bash
jq '.token |= ((./".")[1] | @base64d | fromjson)'
```

```json
{
  "id": 7,
  "time": "now",
  "token": {
    "name": "bobby",
    "color": "blue",
    "tree": "elm"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nAoI7N6loN_h)

Comment: This doesn't put the claims into the JSON object, only extracts them. See my answer for the desired solution. I do like your method for splitting the string, which is cleaner than mine.

Comment: "in place of the JWT token" was somewhat hidden :). Updated using the update function `|=`.